# Sending files to React from ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I know we can use multer to handling with multipart form datas and ı'm storing them in server and mongoDb.
Here ı'm registering a user and I'm saving the image as string to mongoDb ,but the real image is on /public/img/
So,

```
  const body = req.body;
  const name = body.name;
  const surname = body.surname;
  const email = body.email;
  const password = body.password;
  const image = req.file.filename;
  User.findOne({ email })
    .then((isSuccess) => {
      if (isSuccess) {
        res.json("User exists!");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  const user = new User({
    name,
    surname,
    email,
    password,
    image,
  });
  user
    .save()
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.json("Something went wrong!");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Now I wanna send the user which is requested;
How do ı access the image from /public/img
bcz user.image is String.
Should ı send the image seperately?

```
exports.getUserById = async (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req._id).then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

read the image file from stored location with filename and send it as data:image/png;base64 string as part of same response, so that it can be used direct in img src attribute,

Comment: I mean is it effective and is there any resource that you can suggest to me ?
Thank you btw.